Метод setPosition() для балуна работает некорректноо в yamaps
Пожскажите, плз, принцип работы метода setPosition для балуна в yandex maps.
Необходимо, чтобы балун открывался в центре полигона. Подписываюсь на событие open для балуна, в нем сечу координаты центра полигона при помощи setPosition.  После этого балун открывается либо в левом верхнем, либо в правом верхнем углу полигона, но не в центре.

Напишите, пожалуйста, пример кода, в котором балун ведёт себя описанным образом. Лучше всего оформить его в песочнице, например в jsbin.com или codepen.io.
